# Generate HTML with loop and variables in php

Tags: php, loops, variables

I'm trying to generate some html with a loop. Basically I'm doing something like this

```
$day1 = 'Monday';
$day2 = 'Tuesday';
$day3 = 'Wedensday';
$day4 = 'Thursday';
$day5 = 'Friday';
$day6 = 'Saturday';
$day7 = 'Sunday';

$query = "SELECT * FROM skridt_participants WHERE id = '1'";
          if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
             for($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
              $dailysteps = "day" . $i;
              echo $day{$i} . ": <input placeholder='" . number_format($row[$dailysteps], 0, ',', '.') . "'/><br>";
             }
            }
           }
```

It's the first part of the echo that is causing me problems.
I wan't to use variables $day1 then $day2 etc.

The HTML come out like this

```
: <input placeholder='13.395'/><br>: <input placeholder='23.103'/><br>: <input placeholder='15.274'/>
```

I can't get it to work though. How do I make these variables dynamically in a loop?

Comment: what is in $day??

Comment: Use array maybe ?

Comment: variables I need to use

Comment: what error are you getting??

Comment: I updated the desciptions.
The error is that nothing shows where the varibles are, the rest works fine :(

Comment: What does error reporting show http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php, and/or HTML source? Do a var_dump() also and `mysqli_error($link)` on the query.

Comment: I don't get an error, no text shows where the variable is

Comment: try $row['".$dailysteps."'] in single quotes

Comment: You're 100% sure that you're not getting any php errors? I don't see error reporting and have trouble believing that you tested it within such a short period of time of my giving you the link for it.

Comment: The html shows fine except where the the $day1 variable is.
The HTML source is blank at the variables place. I get the data from the database and that shows, but not the $day variable

Comment: I add a copy of some of the HTML in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of you already have a variable containing the string "dayX" that is `$dailysteps = "day" . $i;` you might just transform your echo line in:

```
echo ${$dailysteps} . ": <input placeholder='" . number_format($row[$dailysteps], 0, ',', '.') . "'/><br>";
```

Is this modification enough to fix your issue?